# Copies of ax+b inside the AN part of an Iwasawa decomposition?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gr.group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, reference-request

As a relative novice to the structure theory of Lie algebras and Lie groups, the following is what I can gather from reading parts of Helgason's book *DG, Lie groups and symmetric spaces* and Knapp's *Beyond an introduction*.
$\newcommand{\Real}{{\mathbb R}}\newcommand{\fa}{{\sf a}}\newcommand{\fg}{{\sf g}}\newcommand{\fk}{{\sf k}}\newcommand{\fn}{{\sf n}}$

Let $G$ be a connected, semisimple, non-compact Lie group (over the reals, **not necessarily a matrix group**, and **not necessarily with finite centre**), let $\fg=\fk\oplus \fa\oplus\fn$ be an Iwasawa decomposition of its Lie algebra, and let $G=KAN$ be the corresponding "global" Iwasawa decomposition. Since $G$ is non-compact, both $A$ and $N$ are non-trivial; moreover, both are in fact closed, simply connected subgroups of $G$.

It is observed in Helgason's book that if $\fg$ is the Lie algebra of $G$ and $\fn$ is the nilpotent subalgebra constructed in the Iwasawa decomposition at the Lie algebra level, then for each  $x\in \fn$ we can find $h\in\fg$ such that $[h,x]=x$. (This is one of the steps in the proof of the Jacobson-Morozov theorem on existence of copies of ${\sf sl}(2,\Real)$ inside $\fg$.)

> Q1. Can we always find $x\in\fn$, $x\neq 0$, and $h\in\fa$, such that $[h,x]=x$?

I suspect that one could modify Jacobson's argument (*Proc. AMS* 1951) or the version Helgason gives, due to Kostant (*Amer. J. Math.* 1959, Section 3) to do this, but I have not succeeded in nailing down an argument.

If the answer to Q1 is positive, then I think we should be able to exponentiate $h$ and $x$ and obtain a **closed** and **simply connected** subgroup of $AN$,  which would then be isomorphic to the so-called $ax+b$ group ${\Real}\rtimes {\Real}_+^*$. (Of course one can see this directly for $SL(2,\Real)$ and thence for $SL(n,\Real)$, which is the case that motivated the present question.)

> Q2. Assuming it is true that $AN$ always contains a closed copy of the $ax+b$ group, is this standard knowledge for which there exists a reasonably precise citation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an elementary argument addressing Q1. The adjoint action of the subalgebra $\mathfrak{a}$ on $\mathfrak{g}$ has the following two key properties:

1. It is diagonalizable (the operators $ad(H)$ for $H\in\mathfrak{a}$ are symmetric with respect to the Killing form);
2. It stabilizes $\mathfrak{n}$.

It follows that either $\mathfrak{a}$ centralizes $\mathfrak{n}$ or there exists an element $H\in\mathfrak{a}$ with a non-zero eigenvalue. In the latter case, rescaling, we get a pair $H\in\mathfrak{a}, X\in\mathfrak{n}$ such that $[H,X]=ad(H)X=X.$ As Yves has already remarked, the former case is never realized since the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ is semisimple.

Comment: It seems that Q2 falls under "folklore" so your answer is as good as I can hope for. By the way, you get a small mention in http://arxiv.org/abs/1304.3710

Comment: Thank you for the link to your paper - I was glad to be able to help by answering your question. As far as I could tell, the "small mention" seems to be a vague reference to "various Mathoverflow contributors" at the top of p.3, rather than a specific list of questions/contributors.

Comment: You're mentioned after Prop6.3 on page 20, but not explicitly in the references since I was able afterwards to extract what you point out from Knapp's book. I would be happy to add a formal reference to you by name, as personal communication via MO, if you would prefer.

Answer (score 2):

Every linear algebraic group over a field $K$ of characteristic zero that is not nilpotent-by-anisotropic contains a Zariski closed subgroup isomorphic over $K$ to a non-direct semidirect product of the multiplicative group by the additive group. In particular the real points contain an $ax+b$-group. This can be applied to $AN$.

Proof: if the reductive quotient is not abelian-by-anisotropic, then it contains a subgroup isogeneous to $\text{SL}_2$ and we're done. Otherwise, the connected isotropic part $D$ of the reductive Levi factor (which is abelian) does not centralize the unipotent radical. Define weights on the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{u}$ according to the action of $D$. Pick a nonzero weight $\alpha$ and consider the corresponding subgroup $\mathfrak{u}_\alpha$. Changing $\alpha$ if necessary, we can suppose that $2\alpha$ is not a weight, so $\mathfrak{u}_\alpha$ is commutative. Then it is easy to find a group as required in $DU_\alpha$.

[In your setting, since $A$ is an isotropic connected torus and $N$ is unipotent, to say that $AN$ is not nilpotent-by-anisotropic just means that $A$ does not centralize $N$; there are too many ways to check this to pick one :)]

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response. Unfortunately, as I *really* am a novice to this kind of "basic structure theory" it will take me a long time to digest...

Comment: I should also remark that the work for which I want to use this result is being written by *soi-disants* "functional analysts / abstract harmonic analysts" for the same audience, so facts about algebraic groups such as "if the reductive quotient is not abelian-by-anisotropic, then it contains a subgroup isogeneous to SL_2" would probably need a further citation...

Comment: For a general connected Lie group, there is this statement: any connected Lie group not of type R (x) has a closed subgroup isomorphic to either the affine group $\mathbf{R}\rtimes\mathbf{R}$ or a semidirect product $\mathbf{R}^2\rtimes\mathbf{R}$, where the action is by (non-isometric) stretch rotations. In the algebraic setting we can avoid the second case. [(x) Type R means all eigenvalues in the adjoint representation are real; this characterizes connected Lie group with polynomial growth.] I unfortunately don't have any reference although this was probably known in the 50's or 60's

Comment: Thanks, Yves. So although $G$ might not be the group of real points of an algebraic group, $AN$ always is?

Comment: Er, I spoke of $AN$ when $G$ is assumed semisimple (and implicity assumed with finite center, e.g. algebraic). In general a connected solvable Lie group has no $AN$ decomposition.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion (and yes of course the solvable subgroup $AN$ is not typical of connected solvable Lie groups). (1) I should stress that I am not assuming $G$ is simply connected. (2) So, is your answer only for semisimple *algebraic* groups?

Comment: I'm not sure what the Iwasawa decomposition is when the semisimple group has infinite center. Anyway there is no serious issue: you can argue when the center is trivial, and then lift the affine group to a covering.

Comment: Or alternatively, the following holds (as a particular case of my first comment): if $G$ is a purely real connected Lie group (this means that all eigenvalues in the adjoint representation are real; this forces $G$ to be solvable). If $G$ is not nilpotent, then $G$ has  a closed subgroup isomorphic to the affine group $\mathbf{R}\rtimes\mathbf{R}$. Unlike being algebraic, this setting is invariant under taking coverings and holds for $AN$ of semisimple groups.

Comment: Yves: good point about lifting. (I have been rather sleep deprived over the last few days, which is probably not the best time to try and teach myself what is for me almost a completely new subject.) P.S. Knapp's book does the Iwasawa decomposition without assuming finite centre, but in hindsight it is really done by looking at the adjoint form of $G$ and then lifting, just as you observed.